# How to print out a logtable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to make a log table for a python code assignment. The code I have right now doesn't print out a column of it just prints out the log of those two numbers I enter.

Here's what I need the code to do: It needs to receive the min and max values and return the log of those. It also has to print out a column of 10 log functions. For example, if you enter 1.2 for your min and 1.9 for your max, it counts by one like 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, and so on.

Here's the code:

```
 import math

def min_num():
    while True:
        i = float(input("What's your minimum value?"))
        if i > 0:
           return i
        print("ERROR. Minimum should be greater than 0")

def max_num(min_num):
    while True:
        i = float(input("What's your maximun value?"))
        if i > min_num:
            return i
        print(f"ERROR. Maximum value must be greater {min}")

def get_step():
    while True:
        step = float(input("What is your step size?"))
        if step > 0:
            return step
        print("ERROR. Step size should be greater than 0")

def logtable(min_num, max_num, step):
    while min_num < max_num:
        print(f"{min_num} {math.log10(min_num):.4}")
        min_num += step


min_value = min_num()
max_value = max_num(min_value)
stepSize = get_step()
logtable(min_value, max_value, stepSize)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting your input responses to integers, so if you input 1.2, it would be parsed as 1. If you are allowed to use numpy, then this can be simplified significantly:

```
import numpy as np
minv = 1.2  # you can grab these with input()
maxv = 1.91
step = 0.1

vals = np.arange(minv, maxv, step)
print(np.log10(vals))
```

Note that I used `maxv=1.91` instead of `maxv=1.9` to avoid cutoff at 1.9.

If you can't use numpy, then first you need to fix a few things in your code:

- replace `I` with `i` in function return statements;
- add a closing parenthesis in get_step() call;
- replace `int()` with `float()` in your `input()` statements if you're dealing with floats instead of ints.

Comment: We aren't allowed to use numpy, I don't think. We haven't even learned about it

Comment: I edited the answer to avoid numpy.

Comment: Would you know how to break up my log table function? I need a separate function to take the log of a number and return it with the number rounded to four decimal places

Comment: Also I fixed the things in the code above

Comment: Great! Does everything work for you then? If so, you should mark the answer as accepted. Regarding your follow-up question, it's considered best practice on SO to post individual questions, so please consider posting another question. But to steer you in the right direction, look at `round(val, 4)` for rounding.

Comment: Kinda, I can edit my question and show what its suppose to look like

Comment: Ok, wait nevermind it does what it needs to thank you

Comment: Anytime! :) Good luck!